# Cambiar atributo selected según el resultado de la consulta (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Quiero desplegar una tabla con mysql y ajax con una etiqueta selected en una de sus celdas, y aquí la cuestión (ya lo tengo) ¿Cómo logro que el valor mostrado en el desplegable sea el que está en la base de datos?

Considero que no necesito copiar el código.

Comment: A que te refieres con desplegable? A tu pregunta le faltan mas detalles, deberías poner el código para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: La respuesta es sencilla, cuando creas el desplegable debes asignarle el valor de la columna de la fila actual por medio del atributo *value* (suponiendo que iteras un array de objetos que son los registros obtenidos por AJAX y que, por cada uno, creas un elemento *tr*).

Comment: Agrega el código relevante a tu pregunta y **lo que has intentado**.

Comment: Primero, gracias. Voy a tratar de explicarme:

Comment: Considero que sí necesitas copiar la parte relevante de tu código en la pregunta. Encontrarás el botón para [edit] al pié de la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, gracias. 
Voy a tratar de explicarme: Tengo una tabla que sale de mysql usando php. Un campo llamado 'estado' es un `<select>` que quiero que al mostrarse la tabla la primera opción, la que tiene el atributo `selected` sea precisamente la que aparece en la base de datos. Ej: Si en la consulta aparece que el estado con id=1 es 'perdida' quiero que esa palabra sea la que tenga el atributo `selected`.
He hecho esto:

```
<?php 

    require("conexion.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bicicletas";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $opciones = array( 'activa', 'perdida', 'encontrada' );

    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>
            <table align='center' class='table table-hover'>
              <thead>
                <tr><th>Estado</th></tr>
                </thead>";

    while($registro = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo "<tbody>
                <tr style='text-align: center;' class='tr'>
                <!--ESTADO-->
                  <td id='estado' data id_estado='".$registro['id_bicicletas']."'>
              <select>";
                  $valor = $registro['estado'];
                  $resultado = '';
                    for( $i=0; $i<count($opciones); $i++ ) {
                      $resultado .= '<option '.( $valor == $opciones[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ).'>'.$opciones[$i]
             . '</option>';}
              echo $resultado;
              echo "</select>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                 </table> </div>";
}
 ?>
```

Finalmente funciona. Espero que este código sirva de aporte al foro y de ayuda a quien lo necesite ;).

Comment: Me alegro que ya funcione, Diana. Por si no sabes aún, puedes aceptar tus propias respuestas ;)

Comment: Disculpa, cómo así aceptar?. @GustavoGarcía

Comment: Para mantener un orden en el sitio y para fines informativos, una pregunta tiene una respuesta «aceptada» por parte del autor de la pregunta, lo cual indica que esa respuesta dió o asistió con la solución del problema. Pasa el cursor sobre la flecha al costado de tu respuesta y verás un check.

Comment: Listo! Esperaré los dos días ;)